# Which design pattern suits this situation?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

So far, most of the objects I've been dealing with look very much like the database tables they are based on. So I have a fish object that maps the db.fish table and a fish_transfer object that maps the db.fish_transfer table, etc.

Now I'm working on a class, `Provenance` that manages data that doesn't easily map to a single database table. Here's the situation:

Each fish has a provenance, ie information about where it was before it entered our system. There are 4 kinds of provenance: 'unknown', 'delivered', 'bred onsite', 'reuse'. All provenances have a fish_id and a date associated and all except 'bred onsite' require a count to be set immediately. Other than that, they are fairly different in the data associated with them and the actions that must occur on their creation/deletion or change.

I had thought to store the provenance type in the fish object. So, on instantiation, fish would call  `ProvenanceFactory::make($this->fish_id, $this->ptype)` and obtain a provenance object `$prov` of the correct subclass. So what happens if the provenance type is edited?

Possibilities:

- call `$this->prov->delete()` and then `$this->prov=ProvenanceFactory::make($this->fish_id, $newtype); $this->prov->setall($data);`
- call `ProvenanceFactory::morph(&$this->prov,$newtype); $this->prov->setall($data);`
- call `$this->prov->morph($newtype); $this->prov->setall($data);`
- call `$this->prov->morph($newtype, $data)`;
- ??

In all cases, editing the provenance type results in updating or deleting a set of database rows in various tables specific to the `Provenance` subclass and then creating another set of rows in various other tables.

Which of the above possibilities (or other) would be the best way to go? What design pattern(s) (other than Factory) should I be trying to implement?

Comment: it might help to look at this as a series of questions: 1. how to represent the entities `Provenance, `delivered` etc.. in the domain model? 2. how to represent those entities in the db? 3. how to synchronize changes between the two representations?. Questions 1 and 2 are actually independent from each other, and can be considered separately.

Answer (score 1):

how about having a `ProvenanceBase` class, which has a copy-constructor.
That way, your factory can have a morph method (similar to the 2nd bullet you wrote) which simply creates a new *derived* object out of an existing *derived* object.

Comment: And have all those database-related logic in the copy-constructor? Am I the only person that feels it is dangerouus? :)

Comment: why **in hell** would you have **any** database-related logic in your **model layer**???? I never said any such thing!! damn, I wish I knew how to make stuff here even **bolder**...

Comment: Well, if you do have some database abstraction layer or ORM - you'll definitely don't need any database-related logic in model layer - it's managed by ORM/DBAL. But there is no mention about DBAL or ORM in question. So, where **to hell** you assume database-related logic **are**? :)

Comment: if you need database-logic code- you need a DAL. if there's no data access layer than there are much bigger problems than inheritance / factory etc..

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to suggest remapping everything you have done, however have you considered using Class Table Inheritance.

See : http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

So in your example your `Provenance` table and you can use your discrimator coloumn to identify which state the class is in.

Comment: I did consider that. But the `Provenance` table would consist, essentially, of `fish_id`, `type`, `date`.  All the other data that the various subclasses of `Provenance` have to deal with are in other tables and are modelled by other classes.  So, for example, `Prov_Reuse` has a `Fish_Transfer` object which contains the date and count and a variety of other information from the `fish_transfer` table, but `Prov_BredOnsite` has a `Cross` object instead.